# Mysql in Java: Data truncated for column 'AAL' at row 1 error

Tags: java, mysql, database, arraylist, insert-into

I am trying to insert data from ArrayLists into a mysql table in Java, however I keep getting the following error: java.sql.SQLException: Data truncated for column 'AAL' at row 1.

Here is some of the code:

```
stmt = conn.createStatement();

sql = "CREATE TABLE IF NOT EXISTS stocks "
             + "(id INTEGER not NULL AUTO_INCREMENT, date LONGBLOB , " + "time LONGBLOB, "
             + " PRIMARY KEY ( id ))";

stmt.executeUpdate(sql);
System.out.println("Created table in given database...");

for (int i = 0; i < stockList.size(); i++) {
   System.out.println(stockList.get(i).getName() + i);

   sql = "ALTER TABLE stocks ADD " + stockList.get(i).getName() + " DOUBLE";
stmt.executeUpdate(sql);
    }

for (int i = 0; i < stockList.size(); i++) {
    System.out.println(i);

    sql = "INSERT INTO stocks (id, date, time, " + stockList.get(i).getName() + ") VALUES (NULL, '" + stockList.get(i).getDate() +
             "', '" + stockList.get(i).getTime() + "', '" + stockList.get(i).getPrice() + "')";
        stmt.executeUpdate(sql); 
}
```

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: If you read it again, the exception message is sufficient `Data truncated for column` - which means data you are inserting is of greater length than the column's max length

Comment: How can I fix this. Does LONGBLOB not solve this?

Comment: What is column 'AAL' here?

Comment: its from stockList.get(0).getName()

Comment: How is the column defined in your sql table?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You indicated that `stockList.get(i).getPrice()` is a string, and you are putting quotes around the value in the insert. So you are effectively trying to insert a string value into a DOUBLE column. Normally MySQL will auto convert strings to doubles, however, my suspicion is that at least some of your getPrice() values are not valid doubles. You can try this instead:

```
... "', " + Double.parseDouble(stockList.get(i).getPrice()) + ")";
```

..but if  some of the prices are not valid doubles, this will fail as well.

Answer (score 1):

There are some issues with your table and query design:

Use `DATE`, `TIME`, or `DATETIME` types for storing dates and times. `LONGBLOB` is not meant for this.

The data that is truncated is actually the price you're trying to insert into the `DOUBLE` column. If `getPrice()` is returning a string, you need to check decimal and thousant separators. MySQL uses . (point) as decimal and , (comma) as thousant separator by default. And do not use quotes in your query.

When dealing with prices, consider using `DECIMAL` as type. `FLOAT` and `DOUBLE` may not be exact.